# Udacity Into to Computer Science (Python) Lesson 2 PS Stamps - Output includes "None"

Tags: python

I have searched the internet and tried variations of the code, but I just don't see why I get the Output "None" between the results, when I work on the PS 2 in Lesson 2 of Udacity's Intro to Computer Science.

Here is the PS and my current status:

```
# Define a procedure, stamps, which takes as its input a positive integer in
# pence and returns the number of 5p, 2p and 1p stamps (p is pence) required 
# to make up that value. The return value should be a tuple of three numbers 
# (that is, your return statement should be followed by the number of 5p,
# the number of 2p, and the nuber of 1p stamps).
#
# Your answer should use as few total stamps as possible by first using as 
# many 5p stamps as possible, then 2 pence stamps and finally 1p stamps as 
# needed to make up the total.
#


def stamps(n):
    if n > 0:
        five = n / 5
        two = n % 5 / 2
        one = n % 5 % 2
        print (five, two, one)
    else:
        print (0, 0, 0)


print stamps(8)
#>>> (1, 1, 1)  # one 5p stamp, one 2p stamp and one 1p stamp
print stamps(5)
#>>> (1, 0, 0)  # one 5p stamp, no 2p stamps and no 1p stamps
print stamps(29)
#>>> (5, 2, 0)  # five 5p stamps, two 2p stamps and no 1p stamps
print stamps(0)
#>>> (0, 0, 0) # no 5p stamps, no 2p stamps and no 1p stamps
```

which produces the output:

```
(1, 1, 1)
None
(1, 0, 0)
None
(5, 2, 0)
None
(0, 0, 0)
None
```

Can anyone please explain where the the "None" is coming from?

Comment: If you don't define `return` statement `None` will be returned be default. You need to add `return smth` or not print the result of `stamps`.

Comment: Incroyable... Kept searching for another 5 minutes and found the answer myself: I printed the results instead of returning them. The call is printing the returned values... Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function that prints the result and then you are printing the function's return value which is `None`.

You should pick one method of displaying the data.
Either print only inside the function:

```
def stamps(n):
    if n > 0:
        five = n / 5
        two = n % 5 / 2
        one = n % 5 % 2
        print five, two, one
    else:
        print 0, 0, 0

stamps(8)
stamps(5)
stamps(29)
stamps(0)
```

Or use `return`:

```
def stamps(n):
    if n > 0:
        five = n / 5
        two = n % 5 / 2
        one = n % 5 % 2
        return five, two, one
    else:
        return 0, 0, 0


print stamps(8)
print stamps(5)
print stamps(29)
print stamps(0)
```